# progress bar does't response when downloading

Tags: android

i am downloading a file from a server. i wand to show the progress bar while i am  downloading. when i am trying to down load the file its shows the progress bar. its shows 0 in the bar but i am able to down load the file. the code i use is given below

//onPreExecute

```
             protected void onPreExecute() {

                 super.onPreExecute();
                    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
                }
```

//this is an ask task fordownloading

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                      int bufferLength = 0;
                    try {
                                             //geting connection
                        URL url = new URL(  weburl);
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        urlConnection.connect();
                     // getting file length
                        int lenghtOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.extension");

                        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        long total = 0; 
                         while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))!= -1) {
                            total += bufferLength ;
                                              //progress
                            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        }
```

i use an onProgressUpdate to show the result but no use . it is still in 0 only

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values) {
                        // setting progress percentage
                        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
                   }
```

//onPostExecute

```
                    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

                        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);}
```

Comment: What's your progressbar `max` value? By default it's 10000 and putting in progress values in the range of 0..100 surely will keep the progress close to 0.

Comment: @laalto
i am using Max value of 100 and one more thing i am always getting thelenghtOfFile as -1

Comment: Ok. Next question: How are you executing the asynctask?

Comment: @laalto 
on a button click

Comment: Code please. One suspicion is that there's a `get()` on the asynctask that blocks the UI thread.

Comment: i am not using any get() .
i am using the above code .i am able to show the bar but still it remains in 0 while download. i think it is because i am not able to get the filelength properly.@ laalto

Answer (score 3):

```
long total = 0;
int iterationCount = 0;
int progress = 0;
while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))!= -1) {
total += bufferLength ;
progress = (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)
if(iterationCount >= 14 || progress == 100) {
     iterationCount = 0;
     publishProgress(String.valueOf(progress));
} else {
     iterationCount += 1;
}

fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
}
```

According to your problem of getting the length of the file equal to -1

This information will not always be available. Usually you will know the length of the file you are downloading. Depending on the webserver, the protocol, the connection, and the method of downloading, this information may not always be available.

You should definitely modify your application so that it can handle this situation. I think you will find that different devices using different connection methods will offer different results with this.

Comment: i tried this code but unfortunately it is also giving the same result. Still the bar shows 0 only while the download is going good

Comment: please edit your question and add the onPre and onPost functions

Comment: i got my error ,
always the lenghtOfFile is remain as -1.why i is like that @babous?

Comment: @babous 
can you please tell me why i am not able to get the length.?
is it bez the server is not providing the size

Answer (score 1):

Use onProgressUpdate() method of AsyncTask to update your progress bar.

Refer [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i already use that but no use protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) { // setting progress percentage pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); }

Comment: Are you using publishProgress() method in doInBackground() method?

Comment: yes i am doing  publishProgress() in do in back ground. is this not good?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more override method in asynctask

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
  inDeterminatePB.setProgress(Integer.parseInt((values[0])));
}
```

Comment: i already use a on progress update but no use                             
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
       // setting progress percentage
                pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
           }